# Pause for a certain second Vimeo video

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I need to stop the video at 57sec. I was told that you can use these functions:

https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#addcuepointtime-number-data-object-promisestring-unsupportederrorrangeerrorerror

https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#pause-promisevoid-passworderrorprivacyerrorerror

I am a beginner in the JS. Tell me how can this be done?

I was added player.js

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @DennisKoch I have tried so many things, it is easier to start with 0

Comment: We can help you with your code, but we won't code everything for you